# Weights/bias initialization with constants cntk

Tags: cntk

Is there a way to initialize weights/bias with constant matrices. E.g., instead of Dense(hidden_layers_dim_1, init=he_normal()), can I do Dense(hidden_layers_dim_1, init=W), where W is a float matrix.

Comment: Since I didn't get a response, I am jotting down the solution that worked for me - I added a new linear layer in Examples/common/nn.py, that uses initial weights and bias. 

`def linear_layer_initialized(input_var, output_dim, initW, initb):

    times_param = parameter(shape=((input_var.shape[0], output_dim)), init=np.array(initW, dtype=np.float32))
    bias_param = parameter(shape=(output_dim), init=np.array(initb, dtype=np.float32))
    t = times(input_var, times_param)
    return bias_param + t`

Answer (score 0):

***Update-1***:

*Dense* layers seem to accept a numpy array and constant values as initial weights now (cntk-2.0rc3) as per the parameter documentation [here](https://www.cntk.ai/pythondocs/cntk.layers.layers.html?highlight=convolutiontranspose#cntk.layers.layers.Dense).

---

Layers cannot take initial weight values, yet. However, you can pass in an initial bias value using `init_bias` named argument in any appropriate layer. But, if you must use a initial weight value, I guess you have create a variable and define your own network as you have done. i.e.

```
features = <your_input_var>
W = cntk.Parameter((<proper_shape>), init=<intial_value>)
B = cntk.Parameter((<proper_shape>), init=<intial_value>)

output = features @ W + B;
```